# RedBean условие "И" внутри запроса

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Всем привет, не так давно начал использовать ORM `RedBeanPhp`. И по итогам двух дней, копания в доках не могу понять как прописать двойное условие для нахождения данных в БД.

К примеру

```
R::find(В таблице 'Люди', Рост > ? и Вес < ?, массивДанных[рост],массивДанных[вес]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так?

```
R::find( "people", "height>? AND weight<?", array(1,1));
```